# Manipulate changing controls

Tags: manipulate

Is it possible to use `Manipulate` and `Switch` to change the `Manipulate` controls?

```
Manipulate[Module[{...variables...},
  Switch[type,
    1,
    controls = ...,
    2,
    controls = ...]],
  controls]
```

Where `Manipulate` controls would be different for each `type`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are various
[viewers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ViewersAndAnnotation.html)
available that could used to switch between different arrangements of controls.  For a seamless look, one might use
[`PaneSelector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PaneSelector.html).
If `type` is to have its own control, putting it inside each of the panes ensures `Manipulate` will align them.

```
Manipulate[
 {x, yyy},
 {{x, a}, {a, b, c, d}, None},
 {{yyy, 0.5}, 0, 1, None},
 {{type, 1}, Range@3, None},
 PaneSelector[{
   1 -> Column[{
      Control@{x, {a, b, c, d}, RadioButtonBar},
      Control@{{yyy, 0.5}, 0, 1},
      Control@{type, Range@3}
      }],
   2 -> Column[{
      Control@{x, {a, b, c, d}, SetterBar},
      Control@{yyy},
      Control@{type, Range@3}
      }],
   3 -> Column[{
      Control@{x, {a, b, c, d}, PopupMenu},
      Control@{{yyy, 0.5}, 0, 1},
      Control@{type, Range@3}
      }]
   }, Dynamic@type]     
]
```

[image]

---

*Comment:*
Your question suggests you might be seeking rather fine control over the UI.  It might be easier in the long run to build it from the ground up with `DynamicModule` and the various [user interface features](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/UserInterfaceStructuringAndLayout.html) *Mathematica* offers.

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[

 Which[
  typeSelected == 1,Row[{"you selected type 1 UI with input h = ", h}],
  typeSelected == 2,Row[{"you selected type 2 UI with input mass = ", m}],
  True, "No way ! Please report a bug"]
 ,

 Grid[{
   {Style["A self modifying dynamic Manipulate UI" , 10], SpanFromLeft},

   {"Which UI would you like to see?", 
    TabView[{
      {1,"type 1" ->Row[{"h? ", SetterBar[Dynamic[h, {h = #} &], {0, 1, 2}]}]},
      {2,"type 2" -> Row[{"mass= ",Manipulator[Dynamic[m, {m = #} &], {0, 100, 1}], 
          Dynamic[m]}]}
      }, Dynamic[typeSelected]
     ]
    }
   }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> .5, FrameStyle -> Gray],

 {{h, 1}, None},
 {{m, 4}, None},
 {{typeSelected, 1}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {h, m, typeSelected}     
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Using the command

```
 ControlType ->
```

and then listing the type of control you want, such as `SetterBar`, `Manipulator`, or `Slider` at the end of your `Manipulate` function allows you to customize the controls. Mathematica will also automatically change the control based on the data put in (i.e., if you put in code like this `{frame, {True, False}}` it will give a checkbox).