# Switch inside Manipulate controls statement

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, conditional

I am using this code inside `Manipulate`:

```
Switch[cases, 
     "custom", Control[{{names, True}, {True, False}}],
     "a", Control[{{slide, 0}, 0, 1}],
     "b", Control[{{setter, "das"}, {"das", "der", "die"}}]],
    {{cases, "custom"}, {"custom", "a", "b"}}
```

The variable `cases` is supposed to control which other control type is visible. However i get the following error message:

> Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument Switch[cases,
>
> [...]
>
> does not have the correct form for a variable specification. >>

[...] is a placeholder which in mathematica displays the controls i specified above (Odd, right?). I cannot post screenshots yet unfortunately. Does anybody have an idea why this isn't working or how to better implement a manipulate control in which I can dynamically alter the number and types of the other controls?

Comment: You can't do this. You can't put controls inside `Switch`, at least I never seen it before. But if you post full code, it will help try it out than spend time to try to recreate it.

Comment: It would be helpful to those who would like answer your question to have your full `Manipulate` expression and support code it depends on. Please edit your question by adding that code.

Comment: @Nasser. You're right, but if we had the full code, someone could provide a work-around.

Comment: Somewhat related: [30003](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30021) and perhaps [40037](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40037)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
Manipulate[
  {names, slide, setter, cases},
  Dynamic@Switch[cases,
    "custom", Control[{{names, True}, {True, False}}],
    "a", Control[{{slide, 0}, 0, 1}],
    "b", Control[{{setter, "das"}, {"das", "der", "die"}}]], 
  {{cases, "custom"}, {"custom", "a", "b"}}]
```

The variables seem to get localized properly even though the syntax coloring is wrong.

Comment: +1 -- Evidently Nasser and I were wrong in thinking one could not put a `Switch` in a `Manipulate`.

Comment: @m_goldberg you can put anything in `Manipulate` ...but you can always do it easier with `DynamicModule` ;)

Comment: @m_goldberg But I qualified it by saying "at least I never seen it before." :) I was lazy to actually try it. But I learned something new today about Manipulate.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Could have sworn I tried using Dynamic myself and it didn't work but I must be mistaken.

Comment: @ChrisUnbroken You're welcome.  I've certainly had that feeling, too.