# Is it possible to create a button that shows another button on Manipulate[ ] function?

Tags: manipulate, button

I want to create a program which allow us to choose an option, and depending on the choice, it may show new options. I want to apply this concept with buttons on a `Manipulate` function.

I tried to use `Button` inside `If` functions, but it didn't work...

How should I make it?

Comment: What you need is `PaneSelector`, take a look at examples in documentation.

Comment: What do you think about this topic: [30003](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30003/5478). Is it a duplicate?

Comment: Yes. It's a duplicate..